# Update a Table with a Column Count of another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting an error when I create this Query to update a Table with another Table's column count.

```sql
update  [dbo].[SalesForm]  
SET Pictures = (SELECT COUNT(b.WorkOrderId) as a
                FROM
                  dbo.SalesForm a
                  INNER JOIN dbo.storeImages b
                    ON a.Id = b.WorkOrderId
                group by b.WorkOrderId)
```

This query generated this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

The Sales Table Query, on its own generated these results:

```
1
1
2
1
1
```

I would like to update the Pictures column with the results count values from the Pictures Table as a report of how many photos exist in each record.

Comment: Drop `group by b.WorkOrderId` to get only one single count. Otherwise you get one count per `WorkOrderId`

Comment: if I remove the group by, I get the total amount of all the pictures found in the pictures table, which would equal to 6.  I am looking for the each record to have the amount of photos for that specific record.

Comment: update  [dbo].[SalesForm]  
SET Pictures = (SELECT COUNT(b.WorkOrderId) as a
                FROM
                 dbo.storeImages b
                    WHERE [SalesForm].Id = b.WorkOrderId
                )

Comment: Why do you want to store this at all? Storing aggregate values is generally ill-advised. Use a `VIEW`. Otherwise *every* time your table `storeImages` has a DML statement against it you'll need to `UPDATE` your table `SalesForm`. If you don't, the data will be stale and out of date.

Comment: I am doing this as a baseline to update the table now; then, going forward,I plan to update the column in real time, when I add new pics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add correlation criteria to the subquery so that a scalar value is returned for each `SalesForm` row with the corresponding count. You don't need to repeat the `SalesForm` in the subquery since it's correlated with the outer reference.

```
UPDATE dbo.SalesForm
SET Pictures = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM dbo.storeImages b
                 WHERE SalesForm.Id = b.WorkOrderId
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery always returns a list of numbers, because you have no condition which matches the entry of SalesForm to the corresponding counted number in your Subquery. Therefore, I added a where clause which matches the entry to update with the entry in the subquery.

```sql
UPDATE main
SET Pictures = (SELECT COUNT(b.WorkOrderId) FROM dbo.storeImages b WHERE main.Id = b.WorkOrderId)
FROM dbo.SalesForm AS main
```

Comment: The syntax in your revised query is incorrect. One cannot specify an alias in that way. To use a table alias as the target of the `UPDATE`, it is necessary to use proprietary syntax with the alias in a `FROM` clause like `UPDATE main SET Pictures = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.storeImages AS b WHERE main.Id = b.WorkOrderId) FROM dbo.SalesForm AS main;`

Comment: @DanGuzman You are right. Thank you. I corrected my query.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store the count of an existing table, you would need to constantly keep it in sync using triggers or similar.

**Instead just use an indexed view.** The server will keep it in sync.

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.StoreImagesById
WITH SCHEMABINDING     -- must be schema-bound
SELECT
  si.WorkOrderId,
  COUNT_BIG(*) AS CountOfImages    -- must use COUNT_BIG not COUNT
FROM dbo.StoreImages si
GROUP BY
  si.WorkOrderId;
```

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX pk_WorkOrderId ON dbo.StoreImagesById (WorkOrderId);
```